# What toArray() function does in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Why I have to add toArray() function to listIndexes() to get all index names.
What toArray() function does?

```
 client.db('myproject').collection('hillary').listIndexes().toArray((x1,x2)=>{console.log(x2)})
```

Answer (score 1):

`listIndexes()` will be returning a cursor, so you are calling `toArray` on the cursor that is returned to fetch back all the documents and put them in memory.

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray

Comment: Tnx for the answer. What this cursor is? Where I can find info about it. What else other than cursor mongodb  can return?

Comment: Most things are returned as cursors so they can be iterated on, checkout this - https://www.guru99.com/mongodb-cursor.html